# I want to make a method to delete all elements in a stack that are in another given stack

Tags: java, linked-list, integer, stack

I am learning about stacks and I want to implement the method cited above.
I've been trying a lot and this is my progress until now.

```
    public void deleteEqualToOther(Stack s) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        Stack s2 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && !s.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() != s.stackTop()) {
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            }   s2.push(s.stackTop());
            this.pop();
            s.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
            
        }
        
    }

   public static void display(Stack s) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the stack is empty");
            return;
        }
        
        while(!s.isEmpty()) {
            
            s1.push(s.stackTop());
            s.pop();
            System.out.println(s1.stackTop());
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            s.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
```

My stack is implemented using singly linked.
My logic is that I pop all the elements of `this` stack in a new stack named `s1` and I pop all elements of `s` in a new stack `s2` and while doing so, I will be comparing the `stackTop()` of each stack and deleting the equal elements.

This is my main:

```
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        Stack s2 = new Stack();
        
        s1.push(1);
        s1.push(2);
        s1.push(2);
        s1.push(4);
        s1.push(-5);
        display(s1);
        System.out.println("______________________");
        
        s2.push(2);
        s2.push(3);
        s2.push(4);
        s2.push(6);
        s2.push(7);
        display(s2);
        System.out.println("______________________");

        s1.deleteEqualToOther(s2);
        display(s1);
        
        
    }
```

But the result I am getting is the initial stack.

Comment: `I want to make a method to delete all elements in a stack that are equal to another given stack`
Do you mean delete all elements in a stack that are also in the other stack? I.e. are you looking at the first stack minus the overlaps with the other stack?

Comment: @Pieter12345 What should be done is comparing the elements of an initial stack with the elements of another given stack as an argument. The elements that are equal should be deleted from the initial stack.

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, you are comparing the first element of stack 1 with the first element of stack 2, then the second element, etc. This only causes equal elements to be removed when they happen to be at the same index in both stacks. What you can do to solve this is for each value of the first stack, loop over the second stack to see whether that value is in there, and remove it from the first stack if it is. This looks like an educational assignment, so I'd recommend that you chew on this idea. I can provide pseudocode or answer questions if you end up getting stuck.

Comment: Does it mean that I should have a loop inside the first loop?

Comment: Yes it does, as you want to be checking each element of the first stack against each element of the second stack. There are more efficient methods using hashing, but I think that's not what you're looking for right now.

Comment: Can I have more hints?

Comment: You need to loop over one stack. Within that loop, you need to loop over the other stack and compare the elements of both stacks. If they are equal, you remove the element from the first stack. This will leave you with the first stack without all elements that are also in the second stack.

Comment: Hello, I am still having problems doing it, is it possible to give me the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection1.removeAll(Collection2)` built-in method to do the trick. This method removes all the elements present in **Collection2** from **Collection1**, which is a stack in your case

```
Stack<String> strs1 = new Stack<>();
    strs1.push("a");
    strs1.push("b");
    strs1.push("c");
    Stack<String> strs2 = new Stack<>();
    strs2.push("c");
    strs2.push("d");
    strs2.push("e");
    strs1.removeAll(strs2); // the result: strs1 = [a, b]
```

Comment: The `Stack` used here is not the `java.util.Stack`, as this is likely an educational exercise. It is true that this functionality is offered by API, but I don't think that they are allowed to use this here. Your answer is perfectly fine in general though.

Comment: I appreciate it but I haven't learned generics yet so I don't know how it works.

Comment: My bad, I think as @Pieter12345 mentioned, you need another nested loop to iterate through all the elements from the second stack for every single element in the resulting stack and remove duplicates